# How to do find and replace strings on file after it is being modified

Tags: sed, files, perl, replace, incron

Trying to achieve following:

1) New file gets uploaded with the same file name but with new content

2) Event triggers that checks the file for specific strings and replaces them

3) The file can be saved in place(might be a loop) or new copy of the file is created with the modifications.

For the event catching tried to use direvent and incron, both can catch the event however there are problems with launching the commands to find and replace the strings in that file.

For the find and replace functionality tried to use sed and perl.

SED+INCRON: `/path to file folder/ IN_MODIFY /bin/sed -i 's+/pub/+/+g' filename.xml`

DIREVENT+PERL:

```
direvent.conf content
watcher {
    path /path to file/;
    event write;
    command "/usr/bin/perl script.pl";
}

script.pl content
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

perl -pe 's/old_string/new_string' filename.xml
```

Could someone suggest an idea?

Comment: Are you trying to call perl from a perl script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but I think what you want is:

`perl -i -pe 's/oldstring/newstring/g' /some/file`

If you run this command in a shell (or a shellscript) it will replace `oldstring` by `newstring` everywhere in `/some/file`

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your code, you search for "path to file folder" but then forget of that path in the sed/perl command (not sure the relative path in that case, but in my tests it defaults to `/`).

Why not just use incron monitor the file itself and use

```
/path/to/file.xml IN_MODIFY,IN_NO_LOOP /bin/sed -i 's+/pub/+/+g' $@
```

NOTE: `IN_NO_LOOP` is to prevent the sed command to trigger the same event on the modification.